# Struts2 tabedpanel tag not working

Tags: java, ajax, dojo, struts2

When using the tabbedpanel tag as shown below for some reason the tabs are not showing up on the loaded page.  I have the DOJO lib in the path and the needed head tag.  What am i missing?

Thanks in advance for your help

```
     <sx:tabbedpanel id="TestTab" cssStyle="width:400px; height:400px;" doLayout="true">

       <sx:div id="one" label="One" theme="ajax" labelposition="top">
           One
       </sx:div>
       <sx:div id="two" label="Two" theme="ajax" labelposition="top">
          Two
       </sx:div>
     </sx:tabbedpanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing mapping in my web.xml was the issue....

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: That would have kept *all* of Struts 2 non-functional; you didn't notice you couldn't access any actions?

Comment: All of my actions were working fine. I had the other filters that were required

   <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

Comment: Well, when you don't use the recommended mapping of /*, you lose the default functionality of S2--when you go outside the framework, information like that should be included in the question.

Comment: ...When you do not realize you are doing it it is difficult to include it in the question...